# How do I resolve this "Undefined function" JavaScript Error?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a "Undefined function" [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) error in my error console. Any idea why?

```
<div id="counter" style="width: 40px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var seconds = 60
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = seconds

    function countDown() {
        if(seconds <= -1) {
            seconds += 1
        } else {
            seconds -= 1
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = seconds
            setTimeout("countDown()", 1000)
        }
    }

    countDown();
</script>
```

Comment: For what it's worth (although it shouldn't be your problem), you should refactor your setTimeout to be:

setTimeout(countDown, 1000);

That way you pass a function reference, which doesn't have to be re-analyzed by the javascript interpreter.

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question" on the basis of Waizujin's comment below: "Well, now I got the errors to disappear."  There is no real question here for us to answer in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider adding some semicolons;

Comment: Semicolons were made optional in JavaScript 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

The undefined function may be document.getElementById if you execute this piece of code before the document is loaded. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It stops at -1 for me which is what you have at your 'if' statement.